# Undefined global variables

Tags: javascript, dom, web, frontend, web-deployment

I know that this question may be a "dumb" one but just forgive me for this :( 
I was doing a quiz-time application but just got a problem :(
my two global variable are not defined which are "score" and "solvedQuestions" although there's no variable has the same name... I'm doing this for the awesome french girl in my English council <3
here's the code

```js
var score = 0;
var solvedQuestions = 0;
//prototype
function Question(quest, option1, option2, option3, correct) {
  this.quest = quest;
  this.option1 = option1;
  this.option2 = option2;
  this.option3 = option3;
  this.correct = correct;

}
//creating questions
var question1 = new Question("1 + 1", 2, 3, 3, 1);
var question2 = new Question("2 + 2", 4, 3, 3, 2);
var question3 = new Question("3 + 3", 6, 3, 3, 3);
var question4 = new Question("4 + 4", 8, 3, 3, 1);
var question5 = new Question("5 + 5", 10, 3, 3, 2);
var question6 = new Question("6 + 6", 12, 3, 3, 3);
//the questions array
var questions = [];
//pushing questions to array
questions.push(question1);
questions.push(question2);
questions.push(question3);
questions.push(question4);
questions.push(question5);
questions.push(question6);
var randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
// Builds the questions in the first loop
function QuestionPre() {
  randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].quest;
  document.querySelector(".option-1").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option1;
  document.querySelector(".option-2").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option2;
  document.querySelector(".option-3").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option3;

}
QuestionPre();
// resets them after answering
function QuestionReset() {
  randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].quest;
  document.querySelector(".option-1").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option1;
  document.querySelector(".option-2").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option2;
  document.querySelector(".option-3").innerHTML = questions[randomQuestionIndex].option3;
}
document.querySelector(".lock-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (document.querySelector(".option-" + questions[randomQuestionIndex].correct + "-check").checked === true) {
    alert("Correct, such a Genius !");
    score = score + 1;
    QuestionReset();
    solvedQuestions = solvedQuestions + 1;
  } else {
    alert("Wrong mate, such a bad luck !");
    randomQuestionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    QuestionReset();
    solvedQuestions = solvedQuestions + 1;



  }
  // End the Questions
  if (solvedQuestions >= 6) {
    window.location.href = "score.html";
    document.querySelector(".score-preview").textContent = score;
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Final Score !</title>
  <link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="Styles/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>

<body style="background-color: #09d0a4;">
  <div class="container clear">
    <div class="left-score">
      <h1 class="score-preview bold "><span class="score-bordar">0 | 6</span></h1>
      <h4 class="score-joke bold">Thanks for nothing</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="right-score">
      <h1 class="signature bold ">This was made with <br><br> <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
      <div class="container-photos">
        <div class="photo-1"></div>
        <div class="photo-2"></div>
        <div class="photo-3"></div>

      </div>

    </div>



  </div>
</body>

</html>
<!-- HTML radio box code 


--!>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html to better understand the issue?

Comment: Ok mate, but I dont think that this will help ....

Comment: There's no difference between `QuestionPre()` and `QuestionReset()`. Why do you need two different functions?

Comment: @OmarAli Please post this as an executable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we can see the problem.

Comment: Mate , I know its a kind of "being stupid" but can u just help me with the question , thanks in advance

Comment: You’re redirecting with `window.location.href = "score.html";`, _then_ executing other JavaScript code. This is not going to work…

Comment: Why ?  @Xufox...

Comment: Because redirecting to a different page unloads the current page which holds all your variables.

Comment: @Barmar Added the code snippet

Comment: @Xufox This seems logical , mate , any possible solutions?

Comment: The HTML is wrong. There's no `id="question"`.

Comment: Most of your "correct" answers are wrong. The correct answer index is always `1`.

Comment: there is another html document but html doesn't have anything to do with this

Comment: @OmarAli But the snippet doesn't run without that HTML. The HTML you posted is not related to this Javascript.

Comment: It seems to work here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/v04jtsg1/3/

Comment: You should clear all the checkboxes between the questions.

Comment: Well, thanks barry <3

Comment: and also @Xufox <3